# Need to Create Abstract Class for Items

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to create a class for Items? I planned to create it using Abstract Class. So other classes like Stores, Purchase, BOM can use the Items. I need to create some methods in Abstact class like ItemName, ItemDesc, ItemMake, etc., So that I can use it in any other classes, how to achieve this?

Comment: You might also want to take a look at interfaces: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx

Comment: I would add that giving properties names like `ItemName`, `ItemDesc` is not a good idea. Instead, you should call them `Name`, `Description`, et cetera.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this MSDN article explaining how to create abstract classes. And thereafter create derived classes from it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You should look over at the MSDN for more detailed information, but here's a simple mock:

```
public abstract class BaseItem
{
    public int ItemId{get;set;}
    public string ItemName{get;set;}
    /* Add additional properties */

    public void PublichSharedMethod()
    {
        /* This method will be publicly available to all derived members and external activators */
    }

    protected void PortectedMethod()
    {
        /* This method will be available only to derived classes */
    }

    protected virtual ProtectedBaseImplementation()
    {
        /* This method will be available only to derived classes, and they can override its behavior */
    }

    public abstract void RequriesImplementation();
        /* This method is publicly available to all, but all derived classes must implement it */

}
```

Comment: RequriesImplementation actually cannot have a body because it is abstract

Comment: You'r right I just copy-pasted from the other ones and forgot to delete... Thanks!